# Arduino AVR C++: Simple USB HID multimedia keyboard based upon standard keyboard class

Tags: c++, arduino, keyboard, avr

**What I want to do**

I have purchased a DigiSpark Pro Micro that identifies itself as Arduino Leonardo. The same chipset but much smaller. The reason I wanted this is the extra integrated USB functionality to create a multi-purpose control pad with 20 keys (design below):

[image: Control-pad]

Everything is working except one thing, **no multimedia keys**. It takes me hours to figure out what is actually wrong. I didn't find any answer on the Internet and many want to do the same like I want to do: Use multimedia keys on this device.

I figured out it is a library problem and some suggest to change/hack that standard library with useful stuff and unuseful stuff. I don't want this.

There are some other libraries, but with huge amount of stuff I don't use. I want to keep it simple and small as is possible. Just a multimedia keyboard; that's it.

**Software problem**

The problem seems to be a software problem. The default keyboard software does not describe itself as a multimedia keyboard, just as a regular keyboard. The hidReportDescriptor is not complete to act as a multimedia keyboard.

So I copied and renamed the library to mmkeyboard and use this in the project. This is the code I changed so far:

**mmkeyboard.h**

```
/*
  TMMKeyboard.h

  Copyright (c) 2015, Arduino LLC
  Original code (pre-library): Copyright (c) 2011, Peter Barrett

  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

#ifndef KEYBOARD_h
#define KEYBOARD_h

#include "HID.h"

#if !defined(_USING_HID)

#warning "Using legacy HID core (non pluggable)"

#else

//================================================================================
//================================================================================
//  TMMKeyboard

#define KEY_LEFT_CTRL   0x80
#define KEY_LEFT_SHIFT    0x81
#define KEY_LEFT_ALT    0x82
#define KEY_LEFT_GUI    0x83
#define KEY_RIGHT_CTRL    0x84
#define KEY_RIGHT_SHIFT   0x85
#define KEY_RIGHT_ALT   0x86
#define KEY_RIGHT_GUI   0x87

#define KEY_UP_ARROW    0xDA
#define KEY_DOWN_ARROW    0xD9
#define KEY_LEFT_ARROW    0xD8
#define KEY_RIGHT_ARROW   0xD7
#define KEY_BACKSPACE   0xB2
#define KEY_TAB       0xB3
#define KEY_RETURN      0xB0
#define KEY_ESC       0xB1
#define KEY_INSERT      0xD1
#define KEY_DELETE      0xD4
#define KEY_PAGE_UP     0xD3
#define KEY_PAGE_DOWN   0xD6
#define KEY_HOME      0xD2
#define KEY_END       0xD5
#define KEY_CAPS_LOCK   0xC1
#define KEY_F1        0xC2
#define KEY_F2        0xC3
#define KEY_F3        0xC4
#define KEY_F4        0xC5
#define KEY_F5        0xC6
#define KEY_F6        0xC7
#define KEY_F7        0xC8
#define KEY_F8        0xC9
#define KEY_F9        0xCA
#define KEY_F10       0xCB
#define KEY_F11       0xCC
#define KEY_F12       0xCD

//  Low level key report: up to six keys and Shift, Ctrl, etc, at once
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t modifiers;
  uint8_t reserved;
  uint8_t keys[6];
} KeyReport;

class TMMKeyboard : public Print
{
public:
  KeyReport _keyReport;
  void sendReport(KeyReport* keys);

  TMMKeyboard(void);
  void begin(void);
  void end(void);

  void multimediaKey(uint8_t key);

  size_t write(uint8_t k);
  size_t press(uint8_t k);
  size_t release(uint8_t k);
  void releaseAll(void);
};
extern TMMKeyboard MMKeyboard;

#endif
#endif
```

**mmkeyboard.cpp**

```
/*
  TMMKeyboard.cpp

  Copyright (c) 2015, Arduino LLC
  Original code (pre-library): Copyright (c) 2011, Peter Barrett

  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

#include "mmkeyboard.h"

#if defined(_USING_HID)

//================================================================================
//================================================================================
//    TMMKeyboard

static const uint8_t _hidReportDescriptor[] PROGMEM = {

  0x05, 0x01,           // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
  0x09, 0x06,           // USAGE (Keyboard)
  0xA1, 0x01,           // COLLECTION (Application)
  0x85, 0x02,           // REPORT_ID (2)
  0x75, 0x01,           //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
  0x95, 0x08,           //   REPORT_COUNT (8)
  0x05, 0x07,           //   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)(Key Codes)
  0x19, 0xE0,           //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Keyboard LeftControl)(224)
  0x29, 0xE7,           //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Right GUI)(231)
  0x15, 0x00,           //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
  0x25, 0x01,           //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
  0x81, 0x02,           //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs) ; Modifier byte
  0x95, 0x01,           //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
  0x75, 0x08,           //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
  0x81, 0x03,           //   INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs) ; Reserved byte
  0x95, 0x05,           //   REPORT_COUNT (5)
  0x75, 0x01,           //   REPORT_SIZE (1)
  0x05, 0x08,           //   USAGE_PAGE (LEDs)
  0x19, 0x01,           //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Num Lock)
  0x29, 0x05,           //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Kana)
  0x91, 0x02,           //   OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs) ; LED report
  0x95, 0x01,           //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
  0x75, 0x03,           //   REPORT_SIZE (3)
  0x91, 0x03,           //   OUTPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs) ; LED report padding
  0x95, 0x05,           //   REPORT_COUNT (5)
  0x75, 0x08,           //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
  0x15, 0x00,           //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
  0x26, 0xA4, 0x00,     //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (164)
  0x05, 0x07,           //   USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard)(Key Codes)
  0x19, 0x00,           //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Reserved (no event indicated))(0)
  0x2A, 0xA4, 0x00,     //   USAGE_MAXIMUM (Keyboard Application)(164)
  0x81, 0x00,           //   INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
  0xC0,                 // END_COLLECTION

  // this second multimedia key report is what handles the multimedia keys
  0x05, 0x0C,           // USAGE_PAGE (Consumer Devices)
  0x09, 0x01,           // USAGE (Consumer Control)
  0xA1, 0x01,           // COLLECTION (Application)
  0x85, 0x03,           //   REPORT_ID (3)
  0x19, 0x00,           //   USAGE_MINIMUM (Unassigned)
  0x2A, 0x3C, 0x02,     //   USAGE_MAXIMUM
  0x15, 0x00,           //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
  0x26, 0x3C, 0x02,     //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM
  0x95, 0x01,           //   REPORT_COUNT (1)
  0x75, 0x10,           //   REPORT_SIZE (16)
  0x81, 0x00,           //   INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
  0xC0                  // END_COLLECTION};
};

TMMKeyboard::TMMKeyboard(void)
{
    static HIDSubDescriptor node(_hidReportDescriptor, sizeof(_hidReportDescriptor));
    HID().AppendDescriptor(&node);
}

void TMMKeyboard::begin(void)
{
}

void TMMKeyboard::end(void)
{
}

void TMMKeyboard::sendReport(KeyReport* keys)
{
    HID().SendReport(2,keys,sizeof(KeyReport));
}

extern
const uint8_t _asciimap[128] PROGMEM;

#define SHIFT 0x80
const uint8_t _asciimap[128] =
{
    0x00,             // NUL
    0x00,             // SOH
    0x00,             // STX
    0x00,             // ETX
    0x00,             // EOT
    0x00,             // ENQ
    0x00,             // ACK
    0x00,             // BEL
    0x2a,            // BS    Backspace
    0x2b,            // TAB    Tab
    0x28,            // LF    Enter
    0x00,             // VT
    0x00,             // FF
    0x00,             // CR
    0x00,             // SO
    0x00,             // SI
    0x00,             // DEL
    0x00,             // DC1
    0x00,             // DC2
    0x00,             // DC3
    0x00,             // DC4
    0x00,             // NAK
    0x00,             // SYN
    0x00,             // ETB
    0x00,             // CAN
    0x00,             // EM
    0x00,             // SUB
    0x00,             // ESC
    0x00,             // FS
    0x00,             // GS
    0x00,             // RS
    0x00,             // US

    0x2c,           //  ' '
    0x1e|SHIFT,       // !
    0x34|SHIFT,       // "
    0x20|SHIFT,    // #
    0x21|SHIFT,    // $
    0x22|SHIFT,    // %
    0x24|SHIFT,    // &
    0x34,          // '
    0x26|SHIFT,    // (
    0x27|SHIFT,    // )
    0x25|SHIFT,    // *
    0x2e|SHIFT,    // +
    0x36,          // ,
    0x2d,          // -
    0x37,          // .
    0x38,          // /
    0x27,          // 0
    0x1e,          // 1
    0x1f,          // 2
    0x20,          // 3
    0x21,          // 4
    0x22,          // 5
    0x23,          // 6
    0x24,          // 7
    0x25,          // 8
    0x26,          // 9
    0x33|SHIFT,      // :
    0x33,          // ;
    0x36|SHIFT,      // <
    0x2e,          // =
    0x37|SHIFT,      // >
    0x38|SHIFT,      // ?
    0x1f|SHIFT,      // @
    0x04|SHIFT,      // A
    0x05|SHIFT,      // B
    0x06|SHIFT,      // C
    0x07|SHIFT,      // D
    0x08|SHIFT,      // E
    0x09|SHIFT,      // F
    0x0a|SHIFT,      // G
    0x0b|SHIFT,      // H
    0x0c|SHIFT,      // I
    0x0d|SHIFT,      // J
    0x0e|SHIFT,      // K
    0x0f|SHIFT,      // L
    0x10|SHIFT,      // M
    0x11|SHIFT,      // N
    0x12|SHIFT,      // O
    0x13|SHIFT,      // P
    0x14|SHIFT,      // Q
    0x15|SHIFT,      // R
    0x16|SHIFT,      // S
    0x17|SHIFT,      // T
    0x18|SHIFT,      // U
    0x19|SHIFT,      // V
    0x1a|SHIFT,      // W
    0x1b|SHIFT,      // X
    0x1c|SHIFT,      // Y
    0x1d|SHIFT,      // Z
    0x2f,          // [
    0x31,          // bslash
    0x30,          // ]
    0x23|SHIFT,    // ^
    0x2d|SHIFT,    // _
    0x35,          // `
    0x04,          // a
    0x05,          // b
    0x06,          // c
    0x07,          // d
    0x08,          // e
    0x09,          // f
    0x0a,          // g
    0x0b,          // h
    0x0c,          // i
    0x0d,          // j
    0x0e,          // k
    0x0f,          // l
    0x10,          // m
    0x11,          // n
    0x12,          // o
    0x13,          // p
    0x14,          // q
    0x15,          // r
    0x16,          // s
    0x17,          // t
    0x18,          // u
    0x19,          // v
    0x1a,          // w
    0x1b,          // x
    0x1c,          // y
    0x1d,          // z
    0x2f|SHIFT,    // {
    0x31|SHIFT,    // |
    0x30|SHIFT,    // }
    0x35|SHIFT,    // ~
    0                // DEL
};



uint8_t USBPutChar(uint8_t c);


void TMMKeyboard::multimediaKey(uint8_t key)
{
  //_keyReport.keys[0] = 0x03;
  //_keyReport.keys[1] = key;
  _keyReport.keys[0] = key;
  _keyReport.keys[1] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[2] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[3] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[4] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[5] = 0;
  _keyReport.modifiers = 0;
  sendReport(&_keyReport);

  // Immediate release
  _keyReport.keys[0] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[1] = 0;
  sendReport(&_keyReport);

/*
  u8 m[3];
  m[0] = 0x03; // REPORT_ID MMKEY;
  m[1] = key;
  m[3] = 0;

  // Immediate release
  USB_Send(4, m, 2);

  m[0] = 0x03; // REPORT_ID MMKEY;
  m[1] = key;
  m[3] = 0;

  report_buffer[0] = 0x03;
  report_buffer[1] = key;
  report_buffer[2] = 0;
  usbReportSend(REPSIZE_MMKEY);
  // immediate release
  report_buffer[0] = 0x03;
  report_buffer[1] = 0;
  report_buffer[2] = 0;
  usbReportSend(REPSIZE_MMKEY);
 */
}


// press() adds the specified key (printing, non-printing, or modifier)
// to the persistent key report and sends the report.  Because of the way
// USB HID works, the host acts like the key remains pressed until we
// call release(), releaseAll(), or otherwise clear the report and resend.
size_t TMMKeyboard::press(uint8_t k)
{
    uint8_t i;
    if (k >= 136) {            // It's a non-printing key (not a modifier)
        k = k - 136;
    } else if (k >= 128) {    // It's a modifier key
        _keyReport.modifiers |= (1<<(k-128));
        k = 0;
    } else {                // It's a printing key
        k = pgm_read_byte(_asciimap + k);
        if (!k) {
            setWriteError();
            return 0;
        }
        if (k & 0x80) {                        // It's a capital letter or other character reached with shift
            _keyReport.modifiers |= 0x02;    // The left shift modifier
            k &= 0x7F;
        }
    }

    // Add k to the key report only if it's not already present
    // and if there is an empty slot.
    if (_keyReport.keys[0] != k && _keyReport.keys[1] != k &&
        _keyReport.keys[2] != k && _keyReport.keys[3] != k &&
        _keyReport.keys[4] != k && _keyReport.keys[5] != k) {

        for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
            if (_keyReport.keys[i] == 0x00) {
                _keyReport.keys[i] = k;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == 6) {
            setWriteError();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    sendReport(&_keyReport);
    return 1;
}

// release() takes the specified key out of the persistent key report and
// sends the report.  This tells the OS the key is no longer pressed and that
// it shouldn't be repeated any more.
size_t TMMKeyboard::release(uint8_t k)
{
    uint8_t i;
    if (k >= 136) {            // It's a non-printing key (not a modifier)
        k = k - 136;
    } else if (k >= 128) {    // It's a modifier key
        _keyReport.modifiers &= ~(1<<(k-128));
        k = 0;
    } else {                // It's a printing key
        k = pgm_read_byte(_asciimap + k);
        if (!k) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (k & 0x80) {                            // It's a capital letter or other character reached with shift
            _keyReport.modifiers &= ~(0x02);    // The left shift modifier
            k &= 0x7F;
        }
    }

    // Test the key report to see if k is present.  Clear it if it exists.
    // Check all positions in case the key is present more than once (which it shouldn't be)
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        if (0 != k && _keyReport.keys[i] == k) {
            _keyReport.keys[i] = 0x00;
        }
    }

    sendReport(&_keyReport);
    return 1;
}

void TMMKeyboard::releaseAll(void)
{
    _keyReport.keys[0] = 0;
    _keyReport.keys[1] = 0;
    _keyReport.keys[2] = 0;
    _keyReport.keys[3] = 0;
    _keyReport.keys[4] = 0;
    _keyReport.keys[5] = 0;
    _keyReport.modifiers = 0;
    sendReport(&_keyReport);
}

size_t TMMKeyboard::write(uint8_t c)
{
    uint8_t p = press(c);  // Keydown
    release(c);            // Keyup
    return p;              // Just return the result of press() since release() almost always returns 1
}

TMMKeyboard MMKeyboard;

#endif
```

**The software question**

The idea was to add an extra function for the multimedia keys only and leave the rest of the code as-is. I changed the hidReportDescriptor and this seems to work, however, I cannot figure out how to send raw/unfiltered bytes, to send media keys. See also this function:

```
void TMMKeyboard::multimediaKey(uint8_t key)
{
  _keyReport.keys[0] = key;
  _keyReport.keys[1] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[2] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[3] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[4] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[5] = 0;
  _keyReport.modifiers = 0;
  sendReport(&_keyReport);

  // Immediate release
  _keyReport.keys[0] = 0;
  _keyReport.keys[1] = 0;
  sendReport(&_keyReport);
}
```

But it doesn't work. Itried everything, and there is much different code for keys around the Internet, and I don't know what to use. It is very confusing.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: An alternative way would be to emulate the media keys via winapi. SendInput would be a fitting function. You just need to set a INPUT struct and you should be ready to go. Still Windows only.

Comment: Hi Hannes, thanks for the comment. Yes I could do that but that's not the point, not the case. I built this device and is multi purpose device with several other functions. For example, have other AVR's like Attiny85 that simulate an USB-keyboard and is working fine. Can use the multimedia keyboard functions on these devices. However, the software I used before, is not compatible with this MCU and the MCU got already those features build-in. That why I bought it, memory and features. The default keyboard library doesn't seem to support mm, because it is not implemented.That's what I try to do.

Comment: Here is [an example that works for the multimedia keys "Volume Up" and "Volume Down"](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8934/send-keyboard-media-keys-with-keyboard-library/75466#75466). I use it on Arduino Leonardo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a real answer, but okay. It is a kind of stupid that the default library does not support multimedia keys.

I have started to use this library instead of a changed copy of the default library:

HID Project
https://github.com/NicoHood/HID

This library can be used only with the Arduino Leonardo based boards, the boards with a ATMega328U4 microcontroller.

For example:

```
#include <HID-Project.h>

Consumer.begin();
Consumer.write(MEDIA_VOL_UP);
```

This does the trick (and more). See also the documentation of this library.